# Need help reading file in C language

Tags: c

i am having  a problem when i am trying to read a file in C language.

This is my file .txt format

```
1,325.1.1, ,,,,4,5.0,9.0,10.0
2-5,354.1.1, ,,,,3,5.0,10.0,9.0
,111.1.1, ,,,,3,4.0,8.0,6.0
,646.1.1, ,,,,3,3.0,7.0,9.0
,132.1.1, ,,,,3,3.0,7.0,6.0
6-7,234.1.1, ,,,,2,4.0,9.0,5.0
,321.1.1, ,,,,2,4.0,7.0,5.0
8-11,567.1.1, ,,,,1,5.0,8.0,1.0
,123.1.1, ,,,,1,4.0,8.0,4.0
,324.1.1, ,,,,1,4.0,8.0,4.0
,456.1.1, ,,,,1,4.0,8.0,1.0
12,666.1.1, ,,,,0,3.0,7.0,0.0
```

I can read the first and second line well because they start by an integer, but when i go to the third line i can't read it because it starts by a comma.
Can you guys help me solving this problem?

Here is my code to read all the lines and save them on an array of a structur.

```
int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    INFORMACAO *inf;
    if((inf=(INFORMACAO *)malloc(NMAX_INFORMACAO*sizeof(INFORMACAO)))==NULL) return 0;
    fp=fopen("111.1.1.txt","r");
    if(fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("\n[ERROR]File not Found");
        return (0);
    }
    else
    {
        while(!feof(fp))
        {
            fscanf(fp,"%d,%d.%d.%d, ,,,,%d,%f,%f,%f\n",&inf[0].id_escola,&inf[0].ciclo,&inf[0].jogo,&inf[0].pontuacao,&inf[0].desempate1,&inf[0].desempate2,&inf[0].desempate3);
            i++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: why tag the question with c++ if you need help reading in c?

Comment: C/C++  i think people that understand C++ can help me to.

Comment: I think you need to parse the file with `strtok()` becase there is no way to write a `fscanf()` format string that will always work, so `fgets()` + `strtok()` should do it.

Comment: can you give me some example or one site where i can read more about it?

Comment: Sure. [Right here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok).

Comment: Thanks mate, i will read it

Comment: ugly fix: just add a 0 at the left of every line, it's innocuous for sscanf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This place is getting tiring; ignore the down votes for a reasonable question...

Basically, this is a problem that requires you to [parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) the input string and intelligently convert the data. [fscanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/) will not give this functionality to you for free so you will need to *tokenise* the input (using the suggested `strtok()`) and process the result of that operation.

If you aren't aware of the terminology, that file format is commonly referred to as a *CSV* (or *Comma Separated Values*), so you might find some useful resources if you search for information using the phrases *C parsing*, *C CSV parsing*, *C tokenization*